# How to supply transformed params to superclass constructor while avoiding inline computations with Scala

Tags: scala, constructor, parameters

This is my current unsatisfactory solution to the problem of manipulating the values passed to the subclass constructor before passing onto the superclass constructor,

```
class MissingItemsException(items: Set[String], itemsCategory: String)
  extends RuntimeException(MissingItemsException.makeMessage(items, itemsCategory))

private object MissingItemsException {

  private def makeMessage(items: Set[String], itemsCategory: String): String = {
    /* Format set as ['α','β','γ'] */
    val Items = items mkString ("['", "','", "']")
    "the following items %s were missing from '%s'" format (items, itemsCategory)
  }

}
```

Is there a way of factoring out the transformation so that the transformation code remains close to the point of use while keeping the code legible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an early initializer:

```
class MissingItemsException(items: Set[String], itemsCategory: String) extends {
  val customMessage = {
    val Items = items mkString ("['", "','", "']")
    "the following items %s were missing from '%s'" format (items, itemsCategory)
  }
} with RuntimeException( customMessage );
```

It's bizarre that it even compiles, from an old-fashioned lexical scoping perspective. But compile it does, and it does what you want! Whether it's "better" than your solution is a matter of taste, though.

Comment: I regard this as an improvement for two reasons,

  1. The code tells a linear story
  2. No additional objects or methods are required